# How to building custom grep function

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to bash, and I am trying to build my own grep alias to search through files
here is the script I built:

```
function gia() {
  if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "-You need to define what are you looking for-"
  else
    echo "-Looking for \"$1\".-"
    if [ -z $2 ]; then
      echo "-no path passed, searching all files-"
      grep -i --color "$1" ./*
    else
      echo "-Looking in \"$2\".-"
      grep -i --color "$1" $2
    fi
  fi
}
```

the second option is not working well, if I try it, I get this output:

```
$$ gia 'sometext' ./*.html
-Looking for "sometext".-
-Looking in "./login.html".-
```

I never specified **login.html**, but it took one of the files in my directory and searched in it. and the grep fails.

for example, if I have 3 files in **myfiles** directory:

**1.html**, **2.txt** and **3.html**

and 3.html has the text "backquotes"

if I search like this:

```
cd myfiles
gia 'backquotes'
```

I get the results

```
-Looking for "backquotes".-
-no path passed, searching all files-
./3.html:    <backquotes>...</backquotes>
```

but if I was on root, and search like this:

```
gia 'backquotes' ~/myfiles/*.html
```

I get this:

```
-Looking for "backquotes".-
-Looking in "./1.html".-
```

no results came back because it searched ONLY in 1.html. if I had "backquotes" in 1.html. it will come back, but i don't get anything from the other files, it's only searching in the first file and exits.

I know the star is a special character in bash, but how can I solve this?

Thanks for your help in advance.

EMMNS

Comment: Show us how you're invoking `gia`. From the looks of it `$2` seems to have the value `./login.html`

Comment: alternatively you can use `find $dir_name -name "$file_name_pattern" -exec grep -i --color=auto "$string_to_grep" {} \;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can splice all the arguments starting from 2nd in `$@` using the `${@:2}` notation. Also quote the `"${@:2}"` since your filenames can include spaces and any special characters that need escaping.

This should work:

```
function gia() {
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "-You need to define what are you looking for-"
else
    echo "-Looking for \"$1\".-"
    if [ -z $2 ]; then
        echo "-no path passed, searching all files-"
        grep -i --color "$1" ./*
    else
        echo "-Looking in \"${@:2}\".-"
        grep -i --color "$1" "${@:2}"
    fi
fi
}
```

**Output:**

```
$ gia ABC file*.html
-Looking for "ABC".-
-Looking in "file1.html file 2.html file 3.html file4.html file5.html".-
file 2.html:ABC
file 3.html:ABC
file5.html:ABC
```

Comment: awesome, this is what I needed, thank @Tuxdude, but I think I'll remove the 2nd echo statement, since if I have like 300 files (like in my case now); the page get filled with files names,,, kinda annoying... but it does the job

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use 'wildcard' file names to the function then $@ must be parsed. This is the list of parameters to the function. I've left the parsing of the path out of this solution for now.

```
function gia() {
  if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "-You need to define what are you looking for-"
  else
      for f in $@
      do
         grep -i --color "$f" ./*
      done
    fi
  fi
}
```

Comment: yeah, I understand that, my problem is: when I specify the path, the grep fails, and I don't get back the results, I'll edit my post with more explination

Comment: ok I understand now thks - try using single quotes around *.html.

Comment: I did, did not get back any resutls :(

Comment: another solution - hopefully this will be more useful to you.

Comment: according to the code you wrote, this will search the $f text in all files in the current directory.... I want the ability to search in the text in a specific path I pass it instead of ./*,,, I like the for loop though, I will use that to pass multiple texts, but still did not solve my path issue...